# white text on black background in entire table

Tags: tables, color

I am looking for a way have white text on black background in the PDF output of PDFLaTeX  applied to a document containing a basic table with dividing lines and some colored links. Using

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagecolor[rgb]{0.,0.,0.}
\color[rgb]{1,1,1}
```

I gain the desired effect but only outside of the table.
I can put

```
\color[rgb]{1,1,1}
```

in every cell, but that is not practical and table lines are still black and hence do not show up.

EDIT: Here is a MWE; the `tabular` makes room for a paragraph and lcr specification.

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
  \caption{Caption}
  \label{Table1}
  \begin{center}
    \arrayrulecolor{white}
    \newcolumntype{B}{>{\columncolor{black}\color{white}}c}
    \begin{tabular}{  B  l   | B  p{6in}   }
      \hline\hline
      Text 1 & Text 2 \\
      \hline\hline
      Text 3 & Text 4 \\
      \hline
    \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: have you tried `colortbl`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do this with the `[table]` option of `xcolor` (which uses `colortbl`):

You can use the `array` package to define column types whose colour is black.  E.g.

```
\newcolumntype{B}{>{\columncolor{black}\color{white}}c}}
```

defines a `B` column which is identical to a `c` column, but black with white text.  You can also define similar column types for the other types of columns (`l`, `p` and `m`, for example).  For `p` column types, you need to add `hspace{0pt}` at the beginning of the cell to avoid odd spacing issues.

```
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\columncolor{black}\color{white}}l}}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\columncolor{black}\hspace{0pt}\color{white}}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\columncolor{black}\hspace{0pt}\color{white}}m{#1}}
```

Here's an example using each type.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\arrayrulecolor{white}
\newcolumntype{B}{>{\columncolor{black}\color{white}}c}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\columncolor{black}\color{white}}l}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\columncolor{black}\hspace{0pt}\color{white}}p{#1}}
\begin{tabular}{|B|L|P{1in}|}
\hline
A & B & C \\
\hline
D & E & F \\
\hline
G & H & I \\
\hline
J & K & L \\
\hline
M & N & O \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: @Munn  I tried with my table and I got mixed results. Questions is what if begin{tabular}  has more specs such as edited example above.

Comment: @Maesumi I've added some other column types to the example.

Comment: @Munn (Werner) Thanks. Everything works, except when I use \newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\columncolor{black}\color{white}}p{#1}} I get an extra line in the table with the corresponding cell pushed into the second line. By the way, regarding the ![\hline and \end{document}][1], are they typos?

Comment: @Maesumi I've modified the definition of the `P` column type to fix the spacing issue.  (And yes, there were some typos introduced by a bad paste when I was editing.)

Answer (score 1):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\color{white}
\begin{NiceTabular}{clp{1in}}[rules/color=white,hvlines-except-borders]
\CodeBefore
\arraycolor{black}
\Body
A & B & C \\
D & E & F \\
G & H & I \\
J & K & L \\
M & N & O \\
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]